# how to set print title rows in excel sheet using POI?

Tags: java, excel, printing, apache-poi

I'd like to set print title rows so header would be printed on the top of every page
I'm using POI 2.5.1

Comment: You are aware that the latest stable release of POI is v3.9, right?  You'll have much better luck getting help and implementing newer features with all of the new developments in the library in the last **7** (!!!) years.

Answer (score 9):

First, don't use such an old version of POI.  The latest stable version as of this writing is 3.9.

To answer your actual question, you can use the [`setRepeatingRows` method in the `Sheet` interface](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRepeatingRows%28org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress%29).  (As of Apache POI 3.5, .xlsx is supported with the `org.apache.poi.xssf.*` packages.  A common interface was developed in the `org.apache.poi.ss.*` packages, and almost everything "HSSF" has been extracted into common interfaces, e.g. `HSSFSheet` implements `Sheet`.  Similarly, almost everything "XSSF" implements those same interfaces also.)

In fact, the [Busy Developer's Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Repeating) contains an example of its usage:

```
// Set the rows to repeat from row 4 to 5 on the first sheet.
sheet1.setRepeatingRows(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("4:5"));
```